# LEFT JOIN ON condition AND another condition in Doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony4

I am using Symfony 4.

I have two tables and a join table :

```
tag:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)

recipe:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)

tag_recipe:
  columns:
    tag_id
    recipe_id
```

I am tring to convert this SQL in Doctrine in the query builder of my form, to show only tags not linked to a specific recipe (id = 1 for example) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tag 
LEFT JOIN tag_recipe 
ON tag.id = tag_recipe.tag_id 
AND tag_recipe.recipe_id = 1 
WHERE tag_recipe.tag_id IS NULL
```

For now, I am trying :

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.recipes', 'r', Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.id = :recipe')
            ->where('r is NULL')
            ->setParameter('recipe', $this->recipe);
}
```

And I get no tag at all. I tried several other solution, but every single time, I get wether no tag, wether all tags...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you try "$er->clear();"? Maybe the relation recipes array is cached.

Comment: This query feels odd. What are you trying to achieve? You are retrieving all tags, joining all tag_recipes on the tag_id, and then retireving all where the tag_id is NULL. Which are none?